# Firebase CLI for Firestore Emulator is not launching on Windows

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I am following this [article](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#install-cli-windows) to launch Firestore emulator on my local Windows 10 box.  After downloading the firebase-tools-instant-win.exe and tried various commands with no difference

```
firebase-tools-instant-win.exe firebase init
firebase-tools-instant-win.exe firebase login
```

I see no action on my shell, no message being reported and prompt returns simply back. Any idea what I am missing here.

Comment: If the Firebase CLI isn't working the way you expect, please open an issue on the project GitHub with the steps to reproduce the issue.   https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks, https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1796

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to Windows security and  [github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1796](http://%20github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/1796) has more details.

In the mean time can also use [npm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator) approach to run the firebase emulator

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```